# Xcode sprites aren't added despite everything is set & done including addChild(). Just a basic code tho

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I was trying to test something basic but needed for me, wrote it down but my sprite nodes are not presented in the scene. It might be a stupid mistake but I couldn't find it out. What should I do?

```
var test = SKSpriteNode()
var test2 = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    spawnAll()
}

func spawnAll() {
    test = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 75, height: 75))
    test.position = CGPoint(x: -100, y: 100)
    test.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    test.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: test.size)
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: -1, dy: 0)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    test.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    test.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.7
    test.isHidden = false

    addChild(test)

    test2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.magenta, size: CGSize(width: 75, height: 75))
    test2.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
    test2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: test2.size)
    test2.isHidden = false
    addChild(test2)
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    var radians = atan2(test.position.x, test.position.y)
    test2.zRotation = -radians
}
```

Comment: try setting the zPosition property to something higher like 10. as of iOS 10 you must have the zPositon property set for all sprites

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still didn't work.

Comment: you need to post more of your code then, or give more details. are you running on the simulator,? iPhone? ipad?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell you didn't call the function before the override func so it doesn't know what it is supposed to do. I ran it and it worked when I put the spawnAll() function before the override function

Comment: this is completely false, you can load objects from didMove with absolutely no problems.

Comment: I tried it but still didn't work. But I will pay attention to this point. Thanks.